# Is it secure to send a password over HTTPS with jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, jsonp

If I send a password in JSONP with jquery over HTTPS to perform authentication is it secure? I can't use a JSON POST.

EDIT:

```
    $.ajax({
    type : "POST", 
    url: "https://example.com/api.php", 
    dataType: "jsonp", 
    jsonp: "callback", 
    data: {  password:123456 }
}).done(function(rsp) ....
```

Comment: Define "secure"? From what threat? HTTPS is generally secure vs. eavesdropping, but not against other attacks.

Comment: man in the middle attack, is this possible?

Comment: If someone accepts a bogus TLS certificate anything's possible. There's no way to secure against that though, and generally it's not an issue. Encrypting your JSON payloads is often more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- https with post method is secure

---

if you'r afraid of man in the middle its an security issues that the user have to make sure that he is secure not the developer

Comment: If is even secure when i use  $.ajax({ type : "GET", ... ?

Comment: i dont recommend using get for sending password data ! it's not secure and you'r password can be exposed easily

Comment: To add to what @EmadFani said: Often URLs are logged on your server, so if the password is in the URL of a GET request, you can end up with a plain text record of the password lying around on your server disk somewhere.  With HTTPS, the only information that can be sniffed (barring a compromise) is the server that's involved, not the URL, so outside of your network the URL should not be visible.  But still, the logging is enough reason not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is a method for sending JSON data without worrying about cross-domain issues. And for security purpose POST method is the secure method as compare to GET method.